# Exiting C++ server application on Linux gracefully with signal handling

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I have a C++ server program running on Linux that receives data from client computers and stores them in a MySQL database. For efficiency, the incoming data is kept in an in-memory buffer and flushed periodically to the database (or when its size reaches a threshold). The flushing period can be long (eg: 3 minutes).

If a user terminates this program (by sending `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT`), it should ideally flush the buffers to the database before exiting (a graceful exit).

I have learned from these questions that signal handling is the way to go.

[Linux C catching kill signal for graceful termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376228/linux-c-catching-kill-signal-for-graceful-termination)

[Simple Linux Signal Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942034/simple-linux-signal-handling)

I want to clarify the following points;

1. Is writing in-memory data to a database a valid thing to do after catching a signal?
2. Is it better to use `signalfd()` rather than `sigaction()` as I can then receive the signals via an FD in the server's `select()` loop?
3. Should I catch signals other than `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` in this scenario for a graceful exit?