# Terminating a program with calling atexit functions (Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, signals

Is there any way to send a signal to a process (in Linux), that results in a termination of the process after going through the "atexit-functions" (in this case: `void shutdownEngines()`)? Using "pkill name" does not work.

```
#include <cstdlib>
void shutdownEngines() {/*is not executed by "pkill name"*/}
int main() {
    atexit(shutdownEngines);
    while(true)
       doStuff();
}
```

Usage: I'm currently programming a robot. Every time I want to test it, I'll start the program and terminate it with "`pkill name`", but "`shutdownEngines`" isn't called and the robot keeps moving, falling off the table etc.

I know I could do "`pkill name; ./shutdownEngines.sh`", but this would be very bad style in my case (the numbers of the gpio pins connected to the engines are defined in a header file of the main program (the source code of the main program is not on the robot but on my computer). Making sure that there's always a "`shutdownEngines.sh`" program/script with the right pins on every robot would be very complicated.

## Update

The following code works perfectly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdlib>
void signalHandler(__attribute__((unused)) const int signum) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
void driverEpilog() {
    std::cout << "shutting down engines...";
    //drv255(0,0);
}
int main() {
    signal(SIGTERM, signalHandler);
    atexit(driverEpilog);
    while(true)
        system("sleep 1");
}
```

Comment: It would help you if you get  into the habit of reading the manual page

Comment: When you send a signal to a process, (by default) the process dies without going through `exit()`, so the routines registered with `atexit()` are not called.  You'd have to write a signal handler that goes through `exit()` — which isn't supported by the C standard, and even POSIX doesn't officially allow it (see [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/)) — mainly because there's no control over what the functions in the `atexit` handlers do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376228/linux-c-catching-kill-signal-for-graceful-termination

Comment: Call `exit(3)` in the signal handler or call `exit(3)` after detecting (`errno == EINT`) you have received a signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the man page of `atexit`:

> Functions registered using atexit() (and on_exit(3)) are not called
>          if a process terminates abnormally because of the delivery of a
>          signal.

`atexit` is called when your main routine returns or when you call `exit`, not on a signal.

When you call `pkill` you're sending a `SIGTERM` signal. Handle this signal with `signal` or `sigaction` instead (define handlers on `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `SIGFPE`, ...) to stop the engines before exiting your program.

Example lifted from [GNU C library documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigaction-Function-Example.html):

```
void
termination_handler (int signum)
{
  struct temp_file *p;

  for (p = temp_file_list; p; p = p->next)
    unlink (p->name);  // don't delete files, stop your engines instead :)
}

int
main (void)
{
  …
  struct sigaction new_action, old_action;

  /* Set up the structure to specify the new action. */
  new_action.sa_handler = termination_handler;
  sigemptyset (&new_action.sa_mask);
  new_action.sa_flags = 0;

  sigaction (SIGINT, NULL, &old_action);
  if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
    sigaction (SIGINT, &new_action, NULL);
  sigaction (SIGHUP, NULL, &old_action);
  if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
    sigaction (SIGHUP, &new_action, NULL);
  sigaction (SIGTERM, NULL, &old_action);
  if (old_action.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)
    sigaction (SIGTERM, &new_action, NULL);
  …
}
```

(of course, no handler can handle the `SIGKILL` "signal", which tells the OS to remove your process from the active process list, without further notice!)