# Ruby display backtrace when killed

Tags: ruby, kill

How do I get my programm to display the backtrace / caller when killed ?
I have an issue with an infinite loop in a gem that isn't mine and need to know where the issue is to report it

```
def hello
  puts 'hello'
end

def test
  while true
    sleep 2
    hello
  end
end

test
```

In this exemple, when a kill signal is sent to the programm, I wish to know what the programm what doing ( display the caller )
Currently all I get displayed is "Killed" on the output

Comment: I would try `at_exit { puts caller.inspect }` maybe it helps

Comment: no, it does not work, I still only get a "Killed" string displayed on the term and that is all

Comment: Did you use sigterm or sigkill (9) ?

Comment: used htop and the sigkill option. But if possible, I would like it to be compatible with Windows ( no idea of what it uses )

Comment: Sigkill kills every thing imidiadly. That's the only signal you can't intercept.

Comment: not sure about Ruby but this signal is interceptable, else all anti virus would be completely useless

Comment: Speaking for linux. Only the user with real or effective user ID of the process or root can send a signal to a process. So every thing is allright for your anti-virus software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to catch sigkill signals as they are sent to the kernel and not the process : https://major.io/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/

you can, however, use a "parent" process that watches the "children" and will react accordingly [SIGKILL signal Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908694/sigkill-signal-handler)

This means that I cannot display the backtrace, I will probably have to use a log file or something like that.

I suppose anti-virus have a different way of working to avoid the issue of being killed

Comment: Speaking for linux. Only the user with real or effective user ID of the process or root can send a signal to a process. So every thing is allright for your anti-virus software.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to catch a signal,
Did you try

https://gist.github.com/sauloperez/6592971

Comment: That is exactly what I was going to suggest :) it is the Ruby way of doing it.

Comment: does not work with sigkill :/ ( try running a loop after the signal catching and sending a sigkill signal with htop )

Answer (score 1):

Taken from https://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-gdb-to-inspect-a-running-ruby-process

As a last resort you can use `gdb` to connect to your running ruby process
`gdb </path/to/ruby> <PID>`

```
# inside ~/.gdbinit
define redirect_stdout
  call rb_eval_string("$_old_stdout, $stdout = $stdout,
    File.open('/tmp/ruby-debug.' + Process.pid.to_s, 'a'); $stdout.sync = true")
end

define ruby_eval
  call(rb_p(rb_eval_string_protect($arg0,(int*)0)))
end
```