# Cleanup child processes in multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Consider simple setup of a child process. Basically, it is a producer(parent)-consumer(child) scenario.

```
class Job:
    def start_process(self):
        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue(3)
        self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run,
                                               args=(self.queue))

def run(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        ....
```

If I do `kill -9` on the parent process the child will hang forever. I was sure that it will receive `SIGHUP` like with `subprocess.Popen` - when the python process quits the `popen`ed will quit as well. Any idea how to fix child cleanup?

Comment: If you provide a `daemon=True` argument when you call `multiprocessing.Process()`, the child processes will automatically be killed when the main process ends (assuming you're using Python 3.3+).

Comment: Have to use pypy and using 2.7 ((.

Comment: Don't know how pypi affects things, but for earlier versions of Python you can manually set the property with `self.process.daemon = True` before the `start()` method is called.

Comment: @martineau Does not work - orphans are still hanging.

Comment: @martineau it is not PyPI it is PyPy, I have talked about and yes it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Sorry, that was simply a typo — but otherwise my comment applies.

Comment: For clarification of the actual question here: Do you want to run a function in a  the child process when the parent process is killed with a `SIGKILL`?

Comment: I want to avoid orphan processes from whatever reason they may come up, in the question for the sake of a reporoducible example I use `kill -9` on the parent, it can be anything, segment fault, human mistake from `kill <anything>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the `daemon` param doesn't work for you, you can catch a SIGINT signal and have it set a boolean value to exit the while loop in your children. ie..

```
import signal

g_run_loops = True
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
   global g_run_loops
   g_run_loops = False

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

def run(queue):
    global g_run_loops
    while g_run_loops:
        item = queue.get()
        ....
```

Note that this won't work for SIGKILL (kill -9) but should work for SIGINT (kill -2).

Comment: I do not think there is any `SIGINT` during `kill -9`.

Comment: [You can not handle a `SIGKILL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3908710/3215929)

Comment: Agreed.  A SIGKILL can't be caught but can you issue a SIGINT (ctrl-c or kill -2) instead?

Comment: I am looking for some generic solution to handle crashes of python and it is children. `kill -9` is just a reproducable example of it.

Comment: If the `daemon` param and signal handling doesn't work, I think your only option is to find them with the `ps` command and kill them separately.  A bash script could simplify this if it's happening very often.  The `psutil` library also has some nice functions to find processes.

Comment: @bivouac0 Ofc, that is not a pleasant way. It is surprising that there is not way to make it work like it works for `popen`.

Comment: Yeah.  I run into this when I have a multiprocessing script that crashes.  It tends to leave a bunch of zombies.  I don't know of any way to get rid of them other than killing them manually but I'll watch this thread to see if anyone has a better suggestion.