# How to find out if a third party has killed or broken the program in C++

Tags: c++, linux, unix, status

We know that in the world of Linux-Unix, we can break the program running in the foreground in the terminal with ctrl+C and end the program.

How can I know in C++ that a third party breaks or forces kill (`kill -9`) the program?

Do I have to check something with the thread constantly?  I have to return exit status 130 in my program when the program is broken and 140 exit status when the program is killed.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217037/catch-ctrl-c-in-c

Comment: That's right, it can be done with a signal
But how do I know that the program is force-killed?

Comment: Most signals you can catch, some you can't. And there's no way to distinguish from where the signal originates. It will all come from the `kill` system-call.

Comment: Actually it seems you cannot catch `SIGKILL` (unlike like `SIGINT`). Read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485644/what-does-a-program-do-when-its-sent-sigkill-signal and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908694/sigkill-signal-handler

Comment: You cannot catch or handle SIGKILL. Your program is terminated instantly.

Comment: What about the `kill`? Can I catch or handle a `kill`? (not `kill -9`) I had heard that in the simple `kill` command, the operating system somehow asks the program to kill it, and the program is killed after doing the necessary work.

Comment: What is your actual assignment? What are your requirements? What are your limitations? What is the original and underlying problems you need to solve?

Comment: What I want is for when my program is killed and then the user enters the `$?` command, sees the `130` output @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some signals sent via `kill()` can be caught and handled. Some cannot (like `SIGKILL` which is what `kill -9` results in). Your program is simply terminated and cleaned up by the kernel - it doesn't get *any* chance to notice what happened or react to it in any way. From your programs point of view it is equivalent to the user pulling the power from the computer - the program just dies as if shot in the head.